# How to update the listView in android when the data is updated in server?

Tags: android, android-listview, google-cloud-messaging

Well in my app, the data from the server is being pulled in Json format and then with costume adapter i'm updating the listview.

But when ever the new content is updated in server how to trigger my app to know that some new content  is available now in server. So that app can pull from the server and update the listview.

Just thinking of using GCM, is it a right way ?
Any better idea ?

Comment: use push notification in your application to indicate your app that server has changed data set

Comment: Try using feeds with sync adapter

Answer (score 2):

Push notification (GCM) is the easiest way to go forward for this task. Just fire one push when your server data updated, and on mobile side, when you get push notification at that time just call your Activity and just refresh your ListView (setting whole `adapter` again or calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`).

Comment: But GCM has a limit of 1000 push notification i think so.

Comment: @Uday who says GCM have limits, no limits, C2DM was contained limits but not GCM, limits is for to contains messages, like 100 then when 101 message comes, former messages will be discarded from server.